# Documentation for EMail templates

Tags: email-templates

Can someone point me to documentation on the EMail templating / merge fields available in Magento?

I seem to be missing many default templates and may have to build them myself, but would like to understand what fields are available for the templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some variables are dependent upon the template, to find them :

- Go to System=>Transactional Emails
- Click 'Add New Template"
- Select the template in the "Template" field
- Click "Load Template"

You should see an existing template loaded at the bottom.

- Click "Insert Variable" and you should see a list of variables you can use.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunate not documented anywhere.